# Understanding narrowing primitive conversion

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand the narrowing primitive conversion concept in Java. Here's what the [JLS 5.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) says about it:

> 22 specific conversions on primitive types are called the narrowing
>   primitive conversions:
>
> short to byte or char
>
> char to byte or short
>
> int to byte, short, or char
>
> ***long to byte, short, char, or int***
>
> float to byte, short, char, int, or long
>
> double to byte, short, char, int, long, or float

Since there is the implicit conversion converting `long` to `int`, we can write the following code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    int c = 88L; //Compilation fail
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/Rssnoc)**

But it doesn't work. Why? The narrowing conversion from long to int should have been applied.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Since there is the implicit conversion converting long to int

There isn't. There's an *explicit* conversion. Narrowing conversions aren't generally applied implicitly, precisely because they can lose information. So you'd need:

```
int c = (int) 88L;
```

Indeed, the [initial part of JLS section 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html) even gives an example:

```
// Casting conversion (5.4) of a float literal to
// type int. Without the cast operator, this would
// be a compile-time error, because this is a
// narrowing conversion (5.1.3):
int i = (int)12.5f;
```

There are some cases where narrowing conversions *are* applied explicitly in [assignment contexts (JLS 5.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) though:

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type `byte`, `short`, `char`, or `int`:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.
> - A narrowing primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion may be used if the type of the variable is:
>
>   - `Byte` and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type `byte`.
>   - ... (similar for `Short` and `Character`)

That's why *this* is valid even though the type of the literal `120` is `int`:

```
byte x = 120;
```

Compare that with widening conversions, which are permitted within assignment contexts *and* invocation contexts ([JLS 5.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3)).

Comment: The spec only says that there are 22 specific conversions on primitives types... and not anymore.

Comment: @user3663882: Not sure what to make of your second comment there. I'm looking at the spec for more about implicit/explicit.

Comment: Section 5.2 Assignment Contexts tells what kinds of assignments can be performed without casting. I haven't gone through all the logic but I'm sure it's all there to prohibit long to int conversion even when it is a constant that fits in int.

Comment: I think it's not listed there because `char` to `int` is not narrowing.

Comment: @user3663882: you know that it is explicit ... by the fact that the compiler gives you an error when trying to go "implicit".