# Passing method arguments to the method parameters of type byte,int,int in java

Tags: java, methods, casting, byte

The following method accepts three arguments of type `byte,int,int` and the method is called from another method which gives a compilation error that the method parameters are not applicable for `int,int,int`.By default the byte parameter is not recognized until explicit casting is done.

```
 public double subtractNumbers(byte arg1,int arg2,int arg3) {
    double sum=arg1+arg2+arg3;
    return sum;
}
```

Now method calling in another method as follows

```
 public void call(){
  subtractNumbers(15,16,17);   /*Compile error,but 15 is in byte acceptable 
 range of -128 to 127 */
  }
```

If i change the above calling as `subtractNumbers((byte)15,16,17);` it works fine

When i declare  a variable as `byte c=15` it is accepted but when 15 is passed to a byte argument why there's a compile error;

**int** is the default literal for byte,short,int,long then why byte c=15 is accepted without casting but not method argument.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it guess it's because of method overloading: you could have another `subtractNumbers` method with an int as the first argument, in which case, `subtractNumber(15,16,17)` would call the second one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193883/how-do-you-specify-a-byte-literal-in-java

Comment: by doing `(byte) 15` and `byte c = 15` you downcasted this `int` value into `byte`, so no compile error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question boils down to:

Why does assigning `15` to a `byte` works in a variable declaration:

```
byte b = 15;
```

But not when calling a method?

```
subtractNumbers(15,16,17);
```

This is because those two situations are in two different *contexts*. The first is in an assignment context, while the second is in an invocation context.

According to the [JLS §5.2 Assignment Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2),

> Assignment contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> ...
>
> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of
>   type byte, short, char, or int:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is
>     representable in the type of the variable.

`15` is certainly a constant expression, so a narrowing primitive conversion from `int` to `byte` is allowed.

In an invocation context however, this is not true:

[JLS §5.3 Invocation Context](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3)

> Strict invocation contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> - a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
> - a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)
>
> Loose invocation contexts allow a more permissive set of conversions,
>   because they are only used for a particular invocation if no
>   applicable declaration can be found using strict invocation contexts.
>   Loose invocation contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> - a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
> - a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)
> - a boxing conversion (§5.1.7) optionally followed by widening reference conversion
> - an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) optionally followed by a widening primitive conversion

"narrowing primitive conversion" is not mentioned, so it is not allowed in invocation contexts.

Answer (score 2):

Java has this idea of compile-time narrowing. This allows the following to be valid at compile time:

```
byte b = 15;
```

Most people are taught that literal like `12` will default to `int`. This is not always true. Types like `double`, `float` and `long` has explicit literal (e.g. `15d`, `15f` and `15L`), but non-floating point primitives below 32-bit does not.

That is why `15` is determined at compile-time to be of type `byte`.

In your case, the compiler is trying to perform type matching at compile time. The method `subtractNumbers` has a method signature of `byte`, `int`, `int`, so you must give it an exact match. Unfortunately, during this process, the compiler does not look at the list of available methods before inferring the type of `15`. I believe this is due to method overload.

Consider this:

```
public static void test(byte a, int b){}
public static void test(int a, int b){}
```

Now if you call `test(15, 16)`, if `15` is allowed automatic narrowing down to `byte`, then there would be ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because when you try to cast a `int` to `byte`, you're doing a **narrowing primitive conversion**. Since this can cause a loss of information, the compiler requires you to do explicit casting (i.e. like what you did when you explicitly casted 15 to be of type `byte` in both cases). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28936802/understanding-narrowing-primitive-conversion)

To answer your other question as to why you can simply declare `byte c = 15` without compile error, it is because `15` is still within the range of -128 to -127 which `byte` allows. If you try to assign a larger value such as `byte d = 128`, you'll still get a compile time error. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379983/type-casting-of-byte-and-int)